# What three numbers when multiplied together will have the same number arrangement?

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

I have tried to look for 3 numbers that when multiplied together will produce the same arrangement. eg( 2x3x4 = 234);

xyz = 100x+10y+z

z(xy-1) = 100x+10y

so xy must not in fraction form.

Let x=y-a=z-b for some b>a>0. If a and b are zero, then from equation 1, we'll have

x^3=111x

which will give a decimal number for x, thus x,y and z should not be the same number.

If a or b is zero, then

x(x)(x+b)=111x+b

and b will be in decimal number. So let x<y<z. We'll get that ab<111. I have tried to put all the constraint and using programming to solve for x, y and z but only get numbers that solved equation 1 yet does not have the same arrangement as the example. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: "*I have tried to put all the constraint and using programming to solve for $x,y$ and $z$ but only get numbers that solved equation $1$ yet does not have the same arrangement as the example...*"  I'm not sure what script you wrote or what went wrong, but `for(x=0;x<10;x++){for(y=0;y<10;y++){for(z=0;z<10;z++){if(x*y*z==100*x+10*y+z){console.log(x*y*z)}}}}` works just fine to show the only solution is the trivial solution.

Answer (score 3):

$$xyz < x (10)(10) = 100x \le 100x + 10 y + z = [xyz]_{10}$$

In general, for any base $b$:

$$xyz < x(b)(b) = b^2x \le  b^2x + by + z = [xyz]_b$$

Comment: In case this answer wasn't clear enough, this implies that $x\cdot y\cdot z$ is always strictly less than $100x+10y+z$ so long as $x>0$.  The only solution then is $x=y=z=0$.  This can be confirmed with a quick and dirty script using nested for-loops.

Comment: I implicitly assumed $x \ne 0$ in this proof, since for $x=0$, $[xyz]$ is not a 3-digit number. However $x=0$ implies everything is zero. This is also easily generalizable to more digits.